# Gif image only resizes after fully loaded

Tags: php, javascript

Gif will only resize after the gif is fully loaded. How do I make the gif resized whilst even loading?

I use multiple gifs so they come in different sizes so I can not just do the usual 100% height and width, I want to keep the aspects correct.

**The script I use to resize the gif**

```
<script>
function resizeToMax(id){
    myImage = new Image() 
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    myImage.src = img.src; 
    if(myImage.width / document.body.clientWidth > myImage.height / document.body.clientHeight){
        img.style.width = "100%";
    } else {
        img.style.height = "100%";
    }
}
</script>
```

**The php to display the image**

```
<?php 
echo '<img id="image" onload="resizeToMax(this.id)" src="gifs/' . $myTokens[1] . '/' . $myTokens[2] . '.gif">';
?>
```

Comment: is this related to java?

Comment: remove the onload? that'll only fire after the image is loaded.

Comment: Does the image need to be flexible? Or can you just use `style="width:100px;height:120px"` to "fix" your problem?

Comment: It seems I've missundertood your problem, I deleted the answer.

Comment: Please validate an answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onload` event to make sure your resizing will be effective at beginning of window loading.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    resizeToMax("image");
};

function resizeToMax(id){
    myImage = new Image() 
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    myImage.src = img.src; 
    if(myImage.width / document.body.clientWidth > myImage.height / document.body.clientHeight){
        img.style.width = "100%";
    } else {
        img.style.height = "100%";
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<?php 
echo '<img id="image" style="display:none;" src="gifs/' . $myTokens[1] . '/' . $myTokens[2] . '.gif">';
?>
```

Or hide your image in css and show it in your function after your resizing.

Comment: How do you use it ? I had the same problem

Comment: `window.onload = function() { };`

Comment: what do you mean how do I use it? mate I have no idea im the guy who is clueless at the moment haha

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer and tell me if you wrote the same

Comment: could you shove that into the code I have already given to make sure its all correct...cheers buddy

Comment: The image is the original size for about 0.5 seconds then it expands to 100%

Comment: wait no, it still waits till the end to expand.

Comment: for example http://www.maxgif.com is the perfect example of what im trying to achieve here

Comment: I am too much of a java script noob

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may be able to do is have the image hidden until it is loaded (add a CSS class for example), and then in your `resizeToMax`  function, remove the CSS class that is hiding the image.

Comment: Currently in thailand. Loading is not my friend at the moment

Answer (score 0):

The onload events fire only when image has finished loading.
In the meanwhile, you could play with the css width and / or height properties, or even max-width and max-height.

The risk is that you don't know the image proportions yet, so the image may looks distorted ehile loading.

IMHO the best solution is to replace the image with a placeholder, load the image without displaying it (eg. outside of the screen window), then resizing and displaying it in the correct position removing the placeholder.

Comment: yea this is the idea not to do this, and just have the gif fullscreen whilst even loading